# What are the role of prestige points in Sky Force Reloaded?

Tags: sky-force-reloaded

I started playing Sky Force Reloaded and I noticed that there are prestige points that can be collected but I do not know how and what is the role in the game.

What is the role of the prestige points in the game (what they are good for) and how can I collect them?

Answer (score 1):

Prestige points grant you credit points to acquire [technician](https://sky-force-reloaded-2016.fandom.com/wiki/Technicians) items (the pilot icon in the menu).